# Blurry interface - no settings changed

Tags: interface

[image]

Tried switching AA off ***inside*** blender but didn't help. I don't want to mess around with my gfx settings since ALL other APPS and GAMES work and DISPLAY 100% fine. Only blender is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Change the DPI setting for Blender exe?

[image]

Maybe override the setting inside here and use internal Blender scaling option